# How to run "cd" command in a Pipfile's [script]?

Tags: pipenv, cd, pipfile

I need to make something like this in a Pipfile:

```
...
[scripts]
my_script = "cd folder"
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cd` actually works. It just does not *seem* to work because [`pipenv run`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/#pipenv-run) spawns a new shell (not the same shell where you run `pipenv run`), and runs your command/s there. In that separate shell, it will `cd` to the folder ... then simply exit. In the original shell where you did `pipenv run`, you would still be in the same folder.

You can check that it can access the folder correctly:

```sh
StackOverflow$ tree -L 2 .
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── folder
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
└── ...

StackOverflow$ cat Pipfile
...
[scripts]
# To use multiple commands, wrap with `bash -c` 
# See https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2038
my_script = "bash -c 'cd folder && ls'"

StackOverflow$ pipenv run my_script
file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

StackOverflow$
```

The script shortcut spawned a shell that successfully `cd`-ed into the `folder`, but in the original shell, you are *still* in the same directory ("StackOverflow" in this case).

Now, I don't know what is the intended purpose of creating a shortcut for `cd`-ing into a folder. I assume that's not the only command for `my_script`, because doing `cd folder` would have been simpler than `pipenv run my_script`.

If you are going to do some operation/s inside that folder, then I recommend writing a separate script for all your other commands and just use the `[scripts]` shortcut to call that script.

```sh
StackOverflow$ tree -L 2 .
.
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── folder
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   └── file3.txt
└── scripts
    └── my_script.sh

StackOverflow$ cat my_script.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd folder
for file in *
do
    echo "Doing something to $file"
    sleep 3
done
echo "Done."

StackOverflow$ cat Pipfile
...
[scripts]
my_script = "./scripts/my_script.sh"

StackOverflow$ pipenv run my_script
Doing something to file1.txt
Doing something to file2.txt
Doing something to file3.txt
Done.
```

The `[script]` shortcut would *still* work correctly (i.e. `cd` into the folder and do things there). It's also better than chaining commands, which has been discussed by the `pipenv` maintainers as not its intended purpose.

- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2878
- https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2160

Answer (score 0):

ex) If you want to execute docs/Makefile,you write below.

```
# Pipfile
[scripts]
doc_clean = "bash -c 'cd docs && make clean'"
doc_build = "bash -c 'cd docs && make html'"
```

you execute 'pipenv run doc_clean' or 'pipenv run doc_build'.